# Equation with braces, multi-column and multi-rows

Tags: two-column, multirow, braces

I am working on a paper and need to write something like the image below in my report. Any help on how to type such equations in latex?

[image]

Comment: Something like `\begin{Bmatrix} q,c,d: & \begin{array}{r} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{array}\end{Bmatrix}` should do it (untested)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{View}_{D,T,i,t}:=
\begin{+Bmatrix}[colspec={cr},cell{1}{1}={r=4}{}]
q,c,x: & pk,sk\leftarrow\operatorname{KeyGen}(1^\lambda) \\
       & q\leftarrow\operatorname{Query}(pk,i,t)         \\
       & c\leftarrow\operatorname{Respond}(D,T,q)        \\
       & x\leftarrow\operatorname{Extract}(sk,r)         \\
\end{+Bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A plain old `array` isn't good enough?

Comment: @JohnKormylo It's just that I use this `tabularray` a lot every day and I'm familiar with it.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you employ an `aligned` environment to typeset the four-row column vector. One could also use an `array` environment, but then the contents would be typeset in text-style rather in than display-style math, and the row spacing would be noticeably tighter.

To generate the `:=` glyph, you could employ the `\coloneqq` macro that's provided by the `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\coloneqq' macro
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % to typeset variable names

\begin{document}
\[
\vn{View}^{}_{D,T,i,t} \coloneqq
\left\{
q,c,x\colon
\begin{aligned}
  pk,sk\gets\vn{KeyGen}(1^{\lambda}) \\
  q \gets \vn{Query}(pk,i,t) \\
  c \gets \vn{Respond}(D,T,q) \\
  x \gets \vn{Extract}(sk,r)
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```